# How do I find X data?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

Is Database Administrators a place to ask, "Where can I find public domain data like mailing addresses" etc.  Can someone point me to the right direction if DBA is not such a place.  Thanks

Comment: Would this be helpful? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3571520/what-public-apis-are-provided-by-governments-to-the-public